# What are the past forms of the verb in “Klarheit schaffen”?

Tags: grammar, verb

In the phrase *Klarheit schaffen*, translated as *clarify*, what are the past forms of the verb *schaffen*? Are these *schuf*, *geschaffen* or *schaffte*, *geschafft*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strong verb *schaffen* (*schuf*, *geschaffen*) means ‘create, establish’, whereas the weak verb (*schaffte*, *geschafft*) means ‘finish, cope with’.

Literally, the phrase *Klarheit schaffen* means ‘create clarity’. Therefore, the *schaffen* in it is the strong verb, and you would say:

> Der Untersuchungsbericht hat endlich Klarheit geschaffen.